# Duplicated questions can't be reported as duplicated

Tags: support

Those two questions ask about identificate the same song and *for me*, it seems that is the same body question, but different formatting:

1. [Question #1](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/4229/1721)
2. [Question #2](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/975/1721)

When I try to flag as duplicate any of those questions, I get the message:

*Screenshot about duplicate question can't be marked as such:*
[image: Screenshot about duplicate question can't be marked as such]

*What could be the cause if both have upvotes?*

Comment: I've never flagged something as a duplicate, but I had no trouble voting-to-close as a duplicate.

Comment: @Donald.McLean, since I answered the question #1, should I VTC question #2 or how I must proceed?

Comment: I closed question 2.

Comment: @Donald.McLean isn't the newest that is a duplicate of the oldest ?

Comment: @Bebs Question 2 IS the newest, but question 1 has an answer thus it is easier to close question 2. That's fairly standard across SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What could be the cause if both have upvotes?

Upvotes on the ***question*** are irrelevant in this case. Read again:

> This questions does not have an upvoted or accepted ***answer***.

Questions can only be closed as a duplicate if the question it's a duplicate of has already been answered. This answer must have an upvote and/or be accepted.

As Donald.McLean indicated, closing the unanswered question as a duplicate of the answered question worked perfectly fine. The age of the question is irrelevant.

In a Q&A way, this makes sense. The reason duplicates are closed-and-linked is to make it easier to find your answer. So all the links better point to the question with the answer, instead of having questions with answers linking to questions without them. That's kind of useless after all.

Now, the questions with an answer can receive additional answers which either clarify the matter or give an alternative. Anyway, this couldn't be done if the question is closed.