# Duplicate with no answer

Tags: discussion

A user has posted the same question on Music and Music Fans, then Music sent us the question.

Now we have dupes with no accepted answer:

[What is the name of the girl in the beginning of Dante Thomas' song Miss California?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/8355/what-is-the-name-of-the-girl-in-the-beginning-of-dante-thomas-song-miss-califor)

[What is the name of the girl in the beginning of Dante Thomas' song "Miss California"?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/8358/what-is-the-name-of-the-girl-in-the-beginning-of-dante-thomas-song-miss-califo)

According to this [weird rule](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370/duplicated-questions-cant-be-reported-as-duplicated) I can't mark on as dupe of the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took care of it.  Thanks for your dedication, Bebs!  Don't think your work around here goes unnoticed.  :-)